# Send MailItem, Display MsgBox

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to send a message and then display a notification that it has been sent.  Something like this:

```
msg.Send
MsgBox "Message has been sent"
```

Unfortunately Outlook dumps the message in the Outbox, and does not process a Send/Receive until the dialog box has been closed.

I pasted together a few snippets to force a Send/Receive and then wait for the outbox to clear, but unfortunately this code blocks forever (as the Outbox never sends while the macro is running, and the macro is waiting for the Outbox to send):

```
msg.Send

Set nsp = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set sycs = nsp.SyncObjects
For i = 1 To sycs.Count
    sycs.Item(i).Start
Next

Set outb = nsp.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderOutbox)
Do While outb.Items.Count > 0
    DoEvents
Loop

MsgBox
```

Is there any simple way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 0):

Use the Items.ItemAdd event on the Sent Items folder.